# No syntax highlighting at all for Javascript or Typescript in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: visual-studio-2019

I want to use visual studio 2019 to work on Typescript files however there is no syntax highlighting at all when I open ts files. There is however working syntax highlighting for C#. Right now it looks identical to if I opened it in notepad. Am I missing an extension or something? How do I fix this? Or is Typescript not supported in Visual Studio? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to activate TypeScript language support by following these steps:

1. Open **Visual Studio Installer**
2. Click the **Modify** button for Visual Studio 2019
   [image]
3. Check the box for **Node.js development**
4. Click the **Modify** button in the bottom right
5. Wait for the installation to complete
6. If prompted to, restart your computer